# Ajax Jquery remove function is slow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a table with items and a button for to delete each item(row).

For that I built following ajax function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".destroy-device").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),
        }
    });
    $.ajax({
        url: 'device/destroy/'+id,
        type: 'post',
        data: {
            _method: 'delete',
            id: id
        },
        success:function(data) {
            if($('.form-destroy').attr("data-form-id") == id) {
                $('.form-destroy[data-form-id='+id+']').closest("tr").remove();
            }
        }
    });
  });
});
```

I delete the device from my database and remove the row in my html (DOM), but the .remove() function acts slow. After I click on my delete button the row disappears after 1-2 seconds, what could be the cause of this?

Comment: check your service response time

Comment: how much time does it takes to complete this ajax call? 1-2 seconds?

Comment: That if statement seems wrong, if their is more than one .form-destroy on the page, it will only ever work for the first one.

Comment: The slowness will be from the server, not the code that was posted. So you need to look at the serverside code.

Answer (score 1):

> After I click on my delete button the row disappears after 1-2
>   seconds, what could be the cause of this?

My bet is thats because it takes 1 - 2 seconds before the `ajax` calls reaches the success callback. You can check the response time in the console. For (chrome) Just press <kbd>F12</kbd> then goto the `network` tab.

**Little workaround**
You can hide the `tr` element right after the `click` event.

`$('.form-destroy[data-form-id='+id+']').closest("tr").hide();`

Then remove it in the `success` callback in the `ajax` call. (shoudn't there be a `success` `error` check?)

If the above is not a solution for you, you have to improve the speed of your server.

**Alternativly**
If you just want the user to get a smooth experience, you can also add a little loader `animation` at the `left` or `right` side of the `table-row`. Then the user knows something is happening. Else he might think that he misclicked.

Something like this perhaps:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

On the client side (JavaScript code) there is nothing that visibly slow down execution.

Said that `remove()` on the row is executed only once the success response is received back from the server.
If the time needed for the ajax request to be sent, processed by the server and the success response sent back to the client takes 1-2-*n* seconds then the row will disappear not before that amount of time.

Using the browser inspector I would check how much time actually the response takes to come back.

If that's the issue you have two options:

### 1

let the server operate faster. How to do that is beyond the scope of the question of course.

### 2

accept the server "latency" and improve the interface to let the user have a better experience.
It's not unusual to have a task to take 1-2 seconds to perform.
Once the button is clicked you may "gray out" the row or show some elements that let the user guess an operation is ongoing.
Upon success remove the row.
Upon failure (an option that your code should handle) reset the row to the original state.

---

Side note: as per comments, it seems there is something wrong with your if statement.

Answer (score 0):

A risky but more user friendly way would be hiding the row from the DOM before you've removed it from the Database.

If you do encounter any errors you would have to add it again.

Comment: I said it wasn't smart.

Comment: Because it means you are showing success on client side before you've even actually achieved it.

Comment: because if anyhow not deleted  on db side then showing back the removed row is more hactic (because you removed it, not hided it).Also removing and then due to problem in deletionn showing back will aslo add a blink effect which will catch by the user

Comment: But you could hide it....and use ajax error handler to show it again if needed ... and do final remove in success callback

Comment: Indeed. Hiding / removing are pretty much the same thing if you're using display: none.

Comment: No they are not...`remove()` destroys it...whereas hide leaves it in place

Comment: @charlietfl   my openion is don't hide/remove untill row deleted successfully. Because anyhow user will come to know that on click of delete row gone but after sometime it reappears  and it will lead him to ambiguity and he will think that deletion is not working at all

Comment: I said if you use display: none. Read.

Comment: @AlivetoDie also requires other user notification also...is not an uncommon approach although less common than waiting for response

Comment: It's a realistic approach. Writing a few lines extra JS vs spending ages on making a server faster. Seems like a fair trade.

Comment: @Niels  the question is completley related to respons time from server and code structure on server side. Please have a look on the comments under the question